# Scale down <video> size after on loadedmetadata

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to scale down a video () using a basic javascript script, but, for some reason it isn't changing. I've even tried using chrome dev tools to scale it down but it just scales back.

Here's the basic script -

```
window.onload = function() {
            var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
            for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
                videos.item(i).addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
                    //Tried using target and videoWidth
                    //Both didn't work
                    e.srcElement.clientWidth = "480"; 
                    console.log(e);
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try `e.srcElement.width = 480`.

Comment: `clientWidth` is read-only. You can do as @IgorGilyazov says or you can use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code:

```
<video width="720" height="405" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
        for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
            console.log(videos[i]);
            videos[i].addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
                console.log('loadedmetadata');
                this.setAttribute("width","480"); 
                this.setAttribute("height","270"); 
            });
        }
</script>
```

There are two things to fix for your code to work:

- this.setAttribute to address the width and height of the video element
- the loadedmetadata event: you may not wrap the listner for the loadedmetadata event into an onload listener function. The reason is that most of the times the loadedmetadata event has already fired when the onload event fires. You need to set up the listener for loadedmetadata immediately after the video tag is added to the DOM otherwise you could miss it. Have a look at this Opera [article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/) for more infos on event firing with HTML5 video (it can become a bit tricky). Have a look [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#mediaevents) for a full list of HTML5 media element events